# Sum a list of lists in Racket

Tags: list, recursion, racket, nested-lists

What is an elegant or idiomatic way to get the sum of a list of lists in Racket? (I am new to Racket).

Here's what I put together but it requires two functions, ideally it would only need one:

```
(define (count-reps-per-round lst)
  #| a partial solution with recursion, 
  only adds the subtotal
  of each list and returns a new list
  |#
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) empty]
    [else (cons (apply + (first lst))
          (count-reps-per-round (rest lst)))]))


(define (reps-per-workout lst)  ; would be nice to combine with above into one function
  (apply + (count-reps-per-round lst)))

(define results `(
                  (28 25 34 18)
                  (22 21 30 20)
                  (19 16 24 16)
                  (18 17 20 19)))

(display(count-reps-per-round results))  ; (105 93 75 74)
(= (reps-per-workout results) 347)  ; #t
```

I would also be interested in any solution that doesn't require nested lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with splitting a complex problem in multiple helper functions, in fact this is *encouraged* when doing functional programming. But also we're encouraged to reuse built-in procedures whenever possible, for example we can write the solution to your problem in a single line by carefully combining `map` and `apply`:

```
(define (reps-per-workout lst)
  (apply + (map (lambda (sl) (apply + sl)) lst)))
```

It works as expected:

```
(define results
  '((28 25 34 18)
    (22 21 30 20)
    (19 16 24 16)
    (18 17 20 19)))

(reps-per-workout results)
=> 347
```

Comment: This seems like the solution -- it's much shorter than what I attempted and does everything in one function. It doesn't deal with nested lists of varying depth like nimrodm's but it answers my original question when dealing with a single list composed of several lists. I'm sure this is much faster than what I put together as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is "idiomatic" or that it's the most efficient implementation -- but seems like a simple solution:

```lisp
(define (nested-sum lst)
   (cond
      [(empty? lst) 0 ]
      [(list? lst) (+ (nested-sum (first lst)) (nested-sum (rest lst)))]
      [else lst]))
   
(writeln (nested-sum `((1 2 3) (4 5 6))))   ; 21
(writeln (nested-sum 10))   ; 10
(writeln (nested-sum `()))  ; 0
 
 ; and even deeply nested:
(writeln (nested-sum `((1 2 3) (4 5 6) ((10 20)))))   ; 51
```

Comment: Excellent, very clever, this is what I was hoping to see -- no need for cons here and works on several lists deep which is much more flexible.